# Oracle Query performance : VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE causing multiple executions on inner query

Tags: oracle, performance, join, view, predicate

This is related to a performance issue we are facing with a query involving join on a table and a view (with 70+ million of records).

After an extensive analysis around execution plan(s) on different environments, I could point it to the VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE leg from one of the joins.

> The number of executions(starts column on execution plan) is equal to
>   the number rows returned on the driving/outer table - may be it is
>   evaluating the view for every match on the outer result set.

As the tables involved here are having millions of records,
%CPU and Overall execution time is getting real bad. This is not the case if I add a hint to not push predicate ( no_push_pred); the executions are only 1.

> Is this something expected  with VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE or am I missing
>   any concept around this?

Oracle Database version : 12c Enterprise Edition 12.1.0.2.0

---

I tried to simulate the problem ( or behavior)  using a simple query - Please see details below.

Note: the no_merge hint is added here to make sure Optimizer does not merge the view during the join, so that plan is same as that of my actual query.

*Query:*

```
SELECT 
v.STATUS_CODE,
    a1.STATUS_DESC
    FROM STATUS_DETAIL a1,
    (select   /*+ no_merge push_pred */
        a2.STATUS_CODE
          from STATUS a2
             where  a2.STATUS_CODE < 50) v
  where a1.STATUS_CODE = v.STATUS_CODE;
```

*Execution Plan* ( extracted using TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.display_cursor) ) :

> I am referring to Line no 3 & 4 from plan - Starts column has the
>   value 70 ( equal to value of A-Rows column on Line no 2 - driving
>   table access)

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                         
| Id  | Operation               | Name          | Starts | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |                                                                                                                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                         
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |               |      1 |        |       |   213 (100)|          |     22 |00:00:00.01 |     350 |                                                                                                                                                                         
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS           |               |      1 |     13 |   533 |   213   (0)| 00:00:01 |     22 |00:00:00.01 |     350 |                                                                                                                                                                         
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL     | STATUS_DETAIL |      1 |     70 |  1960 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |     70 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |                                                                                                                                                                         
|   3 |   VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE |               |     70 |      1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |     22 |00:00:00.01 |     343 |                                                                                                                                                                         
|*  4 |    FILTER               |               |     70 |        |       |            |          |     22 |00:00:00.01 |     343 |                                                                                                                                                                         
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL   | STATUS        |     49 |      1 |     4 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |     22 |00:00:00.01 |     343 |                                                                                                                                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 



Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

   4 - filter("A1"."STATUS_CODE"<50)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   5 - filter(("A2"."STATUS_CODE"="A1"."STATUS_CODE" AND "A2"."STATUS_CODE"<50))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct, the `VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE` operation means "The view thus becomes correlated and must be evaluated for each row of the outer query block".

This is a specific kind of predicate pushing, the [join predicate pushdown](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformation:-join-predicate-pushdown) transformation.  The idea behind that transformation is that the view may need to be executed more frequently, but adding the join predicate to the view can make it run much faster, since the tables in that view can now use an index access.

There's nothing inherently wrong with the join predicate pushdown.  Similar to a Cartesian product, executing a view multiple times is not necessarily bad.  Sometimes a large number of fast things is better than a small number of slow things.

So why is Oracle making a bad choice here?  Hard to say without a lot more data.  Oracle is making some determination, using an equation roughly like this:

```
large number * small amount of time
<
small number * large amount of time
```

With a little more detail:

```
rows returned by outer query * time for index-accessed view
<
1 (for a hash join) * read smaller table, create hash function, then read the other table and probe it for matches, potentially writing and reading to temporary tablespace
```

Like with most query tuning, check the cardinalities.

Maybe Oracle significantly under-estimates the "large number" and thinks the rows returned by by the outer-table is much smaller than it really is.  This can happen for a lot of reasons, like bad statistics, using lots of confusing functions the optimizer cannot estimate, using correlated columns with a relationship Oracle doesn't understand (unless you create multi-column histograms), etc.

Maybe Oracle significantly under-estimates the "small amount of time".  It may think the index-access paths for the view are much faster than they really are.  It could be for one of the reasons above, or it could be because somebody has messed with some critical parameters.  It is unfortunately all too common for people to think, "indexes are fast, I should tell Oracle to use them more often by changing parameter defaults".  Run this query and ensure the values are 0 and 100, the defaults.

```
select * from v$parameter where name in ('optimizer_index_cost_adj', 'optimizer_index_caching');
```

In practice, optimizer problems are almost always caused by Oracle under-estimating something, not over-estimating.  So I'd focus on the left-hand side of the equation.  Oracle is always trying to throw out as many rows as possible, and will always look for a way to get the cardinality down to 1.  If there really is a path to get only one row out of a table, that can save a lot of work.  But if there is only one way that *looks* like a quick path to one row, but isn't, it can mess up the whole plan.

If this is a ginormous query with lots of details, it's not unreasonable to give up on trying to find the root cause, and simply use a hint or an extra `rownum` psuedocolumn to force Oracle to stop transforming things.

Oracle provides a large number of data structures and algorithms to access the data.  This gives the optimizer a lot of ways to find a faster way to run a query.  But it also gives it more opportunities to make a mistake.  No risk no reward, but there's no need to gamble on every query.  If you have an outer query and an inner query that work fine separately, but don't work well together, by all means separate them and don't let Oracle try to combine them in a weird way.

---

Below is a quick sample, using tables similar to the ones in your query.  It shows Oracle incorrectly using a `VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE` operation.

First, create some small tables, insert data, and gather stats.  Everything looks fine so far.

```
drop table status_detail;
drop table status;

create table status_detail(status_code number, status_desc varchar2(100));
insert into status_detail select level, level from dual connect by level <= 10;

create table status(status_code number);
create index status_idx on status(status_code);

insert into status select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'status_detail');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'status');
end;
/
```

Here comes the mistake.  Pretend that someone loaded 100,000 rows in the STATUS_DETAIL table but forgot to re-gather stats.  Oracle thinks the outer table only has 10 rows but it really has 100,000.

```
insert into status_detail select 1, level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;

alter system flush shared_pool;
```

Run a query between STATUS_DETAIL and an inline view using STATUS.  To prevent view merging, I added a `join` and a `distinct` to the query to make it hard to integrate A1 and V.

```
explain plan for
select count(*)
from status_detail a1,
(
    select distinct a2.status_code
    from status a2
    join status a3
        on a2.status_code=a3.status_code
) v
where a1.status_code = v.status_code;
```

Below is the bad execution plan.  Oracle *thinks* STATUS_DETAIL only returns 10 rows, because of bad optimizer stats.  That STATUS table is large, and joining it to itself is going to be expensive.  Instead of joining a large table, Oracle can use a join predicate pushdown.  By passing the STATUS_CODE predicate into the view, now it can use a simple INDEX RANGE SCAN operation on the large STATUS table.  10 small index range scans sounds faster than hash joining two large tables.

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 3172146404

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |               |     1 |     5 |    23   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE          |               |     1 |     5 |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS SEMI      |               |    10 |    50 |    23   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | STATUS_DETAIL |    10 |    30 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE |               |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     NESTED LOOPS SEMI    |               |     1 |    10 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN    | STATUS_IDX    |     1 |     5 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN    | STATUS_IDX    |     1 |     5 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   6 - access("A2"."STATUS_CODE"="A1"."STATUS_CODE")
   7 - access("A3"."STATUS_CODE"="A1"."STATUS_CODE")
       filter("A2"."STATUS_CODE"="A3"."STATUS_CODE")
```

If we gather the statistics and tell Oracle the *real* size of the STATUS table, things look much different.  100,000 index scans is a slow way to access every row in the table.  Instead, the new plan hash joins the STATUS table together, and then hash joins the results with STATUS_DETAIL.  The run time on my PC decreases from 0.5 seconds to 0.1 seconds.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'status_detail');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'status');
end;
/

explain plan for
select count(*)
from status_detail a1,
(
    select distinct a2.status_code
    from status a2
    join status a3
        on a2.status_code=a3.status_code
) v
where a1.status_code = v.status_code;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 3579559806

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name          | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |               |     1 |       |       |   556   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE           |               |     1 |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                    | VM_NWVW_1     |    10 |       |       |   556   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    HASH UNIQUE            |               |    10 |   190 |       |   556   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN             |               |   100K|  1855K|  2056K|   552   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL    | STATUS_DETAIL |   100K|   878K|       |    69   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      HASH JOIN SEMI       |               |   100K|   976K|  1664K|   277   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| STATUS_IDX    |   100K|   488K|       |    57   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| STATUS_IDX    |   100K|   488K|       |    57   (2)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("A1"."STATUS_CODE"="A2"."STATUS_CODE")
   6 - access("A2"."STATUS_CODE"="A3"."STATUS_CODE")
```

Comment: It makes complete sense - after comparing the execution plans  (with VIEW vs VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE) for my actual query, I can see that PUSHED PREDICATE enabled some of the tables in the view to get scanned via index (range scan) during join.
However, pushed predicate is not really helping in my case as the view involves (one of) joins on a large no-index column table. I tried adding the index to see if it changes the path but didn't help; have to look at stats.
As of now, I could validate that it is faster with no pushed predicate ( **no_push_pred** hint), and I am going ahead with it.